# Artifact copy only at version level directory

Tags: artifactory

Artifact deploy in the local repository (Repo A) is forced to be in GAVC layout controlled using the user plugin.

We would like to differentiate all the Production released artifacts by copying them to another repository (Repo B).

How do I restrict the copy should happen only at the version level directory in GAVC (GroupId/ArtifactId/Version/Classifier) structure.

Below code works for me to restrict any copy at GroupId/ArtifactId folder level.

```
beforeCopy { item, targetRepoPath, properties ->
    if (item.repoKey.equals("RepoA")){
        if (item.repoPath.isFolder()){
                                def lastChild = repositories.getChildren(item.repoPath).last().repoPath
                                def childLayoutInfo = repositories.getLayoutInfo(lastChild)
                                String childGroupId = childLayoutInfo.getOrganization()
                                String childArtifactId = childLayoutInfo.getModule()
                                String childVersionId = childLayoutInfo.getBaseRevision()

                                if ( "${childGroupId}" == "null" || "${childArtifactId}" == "null" || "${childVersionId}" == "null" ) {
                                                throw new CancelException("Copy not permitted at this level")
                                }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also like to restrict a copy request directly triggered at the File/Classifier level as well.

Comment: I am not sure what you ask for.
Once you have the layoutInfo, why can't you check that the directory structure matches the version element?

Comment: Is the Classifier part of your path (group/artifact/version/classifier)? if so, are you using a custom layout?

Comment: @JBaruch - I have the directory structure, however, I cant get to restrict the copy triggering at the version element. If I restrict to check if the copy is at Version level, it is restricting the recursive copy as well.

Comment: @JBaruch - If I allow the copy below the version element, then I am not able to control the copy request being triggered at file/artifact level.

Comment: @JBaruch - is there a way, I can capture where initial copy request triggered at. I know i can do that with download events, is the request available within storage event as well?